# Transport equation with variable coefficients using characteristics

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the following pde:

$$x\partial_xu(x,y,z)+y\partial_y(x,y,z)+\partial_zu(x,y,z)=0,(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$$
$$u(x,y,0)=u_0(x,y),(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$$

using characteristics.

Until now I only know how to solve the (in)homogenous Transport equation with constant coefficients. In that case I considered the path

$\gamma(s)=u(x+sb,t+s)$, where $b\in \mathbb R^n$ is the coefficient-vector.

I know that any solution must be constant on this path, so using the initial value I knew the values of the solution.

How can I do something similar for the above pde?

Comment: Replace $z$ by $t$ and $(x,y)$ by $x$ to make the notation consistent with more standard notation. Then your equation reads $u_t+x \cdot \nabla_x u = 0$. So the velocity vector at a point $x$ is $x$, meaning that the characteristics satisfy the ODE $x'=x$.

Comment: Also notice that this PDE has some issues: all the characteristics begin, at time $-\infty$, at $(0,0)$. If you cut out a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ from the domain and put a boundary condition down, then there is no problem, but if $(0,0)$ is in the domain then you may need to be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$xu_x+yu_y+u_z=0$$
With the method of characteristics :
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$$

First characteristic equation , from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dz}{1} \quad\to\quad x\:e^{-z}=c_1$

Second characteristic equation , from $\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{1} \quad\to\quad y\:e^{-z}=c_2$

By necessity $du=0 \quad\to\quad u=c_3$ as a third trivial caracteristic.

The general solution on implicit form is : $\Phi\left(x\:e^{-z}\:,\:y\:e^{-z}\:,\:u\right)=0$

Or on the explicit form :
$$u=F\left(x\:e^{-z}\:,\:y\:e^{-z}\right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

Boundary condition :

$u(x,y,0)=F\left(xe^0\:,\:ye^0\right)=u_0(x,y)\quad\to\quad F\equiv u_0$

$$u(x,y,z)=u_0\left(x\:e^{-z}\:,\:y\:e^{-z}\right)$$

Comment: Julian Aguire first posted the same answer while I was typing.

Comment: Hello. I am relatively new to this topics. Can you explain me from where you geht the equations $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$? To be honest, I dont know the meaning of the expression $\frac{dx}{x}$... I would be very glad if you could explain me this too

Comment: @ Marc : This cannot be explained in only a few words because the theory behind the method of characteristics is much more than a few words. For example, see the theorem 2.5 and equation 2.41 in : https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/436.A1.12f/PDE_Meth_Characteristics.pdf

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will go trough it :)

Comment: I think there is a mistake here, the characteristics satisfy $x'=x$ (vector), so $x=x_0e^z$, so $u(x_0e^z,z)=0$. But then $u(x,z)=u_0(xe^{-z})$.

Comment: There is a very convincing way to see if there is a mistake or not : To bring back the result $u_0(xe^z,ye^z)$ into the PDE and see if it agrees. As well, to put the function $u_0(xe^z,ye^z)$ into the equation of boundary and see if it agrees. Well, all agrees.

Comment: ...No it doesn't. The $x$ partial is $u_{0,x}(xe^z,ye^z) e^z$, the $y$ partial is $u_{0,y}(xe^z,ye^z)e^z$, and the $z$ partial is $e^z(u_{0,x}(xe^z,ye^z)+u_{0,y}(xe^z,ye^z))$. Summing these gives $2e^z(u_{0,x}+u_{0,y})$ which isn't zero.

Comment: OK, there was a repeated typo : minus missing in typing (corrected now). Thank you  for the remark.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of the characteristics is
$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{1}=\frac{du}{0}.
$$
This means that $u$ is constant on the curves solution of the first three equations. The solution is
$$
x=C_1\,e^{z},\quad y=C_2\,e^z,\quad z=z.
$$
The solution of the equation is then
$$
u(x,y,z)=u_0(x\,e^{-z},y\,e^{-z}).
$$